# javascript variable scope and requirejs modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs, scope

I have a durandal (basically requirejs) module that starts like this:

```
define(['plugins/http', 'durandal/app', 'knockout', 'plugins/ajax', 'plugins/formatters', 'durandal/global'], 
function (http, app, ko, ajax, formatters, global) {


//formatters is defined here
        var ctor = function () {

//formatters is not defined here
```

I put a breakpoint in the debugger and found that formatters is defined outside the function but inside the function it isn't...

Is this unique to requirejs modules? Usually variables declared outside the function can still be accessed in inner functions unless overridden. This seems like some kind of scope problem, but I don't understand what am I missing here - the inner function in within the scope of the outer one, so what's the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is likely not that the variable isn't available per se.  Add a line like
`console.log(formatters)` inside the `ctor` function

This will cause the closure to include the `formatters` variable and thus make it visible to the debugger.  Closures only include variables if they are used - at least as far I have seen in Chrome and FF.

Comment: Thanks so much, I was starting to question my sanity! It turns out it was there all along... Previously I had a problem with the module not being defined but fixed the issue and now was being driven nuts because it still looked like it wasn't there until I put back the code that uses it!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before and I managed to work around it by defining a varieble just after the function and assigning it the argument. E.g:
     Var fmtrs=formaters;